# Check digit in bitlocker recovery key

Tags: java, key, generator, recovery, bitlocker

How is build the check digit in the bitlocker key? I just can't work it out from the following sources:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/si_team/2006/08/10/bitlocker-recovery-password-details/
http://jessekornblum.com/publications/di09.pdf chap. 5.4

Should I generate random 5 digit number and add an additionnnal calculed digit? but how to makae it still divisible by 11?

here is how I build my groups right now:

```
byte[] randomBytes = new byte[128];
rnd.nextBytes(randomBytes);
BitSet bitSet= BitSet.valueOf(randomBytes);
String key="";
String group="";
for (int i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
    BitSet groupBitSet = bitSet.get(i*16,16*(i+1)-1);
    group=String.format("%06d",groupBitSet.toLongArray()[0]*11);
    key=key+group;
    if (i<7) { key=key+'-';}
}

return key;
```

Of course last digit of each group doesn't correspond to the specs....

Could you please esplain the right to acheive this?

Thanks

Comment: My mistake this code is fine! My error was in the check code control

Comment: Just had to handle the case when the sequence of bits is 0000000000000000

Comment: Please, either post your solution as an answer, or delete this.